# Efficient algorithm for connecting branches of multiple trees with edges to ensure full connectivity

Tags: graphs

I have a problem where I need to connect branches of multiple trees with edges such that every start node is connected to every other start node. Each tree can branch at a second node into 1-3 branches, with the count of branches always being even. I've implemented a solution, but it's not very readable or maintainable, and I'm not confident it covers all combinations or permutations. Are there any well-known algorithms or approaches I could try to solve this problem more effectively and reliably?

1. identify tree with fewest branches
2. connect that tree to tree with most branchens
3. do this for every tree
4. try to connect remaining branches into a ring
5. if there are still loose ends, conect into stars

Comment: Currently the specific requirement of the problem are not very clear. Please edit your question with the exact requirement of the problem and what a viable solution would be. A complete example would really help understand the problem too. If you have a solution post it as a [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science Stack Exchange! We answer questions about algorithms, including data structures and graphs here. We don't debug code, we verify algorithms. We ask that you edit to explain the motivation for this problem and clarify what trees are you talking about, binary, rooted, spanning, or? Then, what is a start node, what is other start node, is it unique? Then, how do we count branches, what are rings, what are stars? Then, what is the problem statement itself, we need an objective answerable question. Explain the solution with unambiguous sentences and its time complexity.